# Remove Style="display:non" programatically using php

Tags: php, html

This is my HTML span and Input line where I set it to display:none (hardcoded).

I want this to be show if accountstatus is equal to animaldead

Here's my HTML input and span

```
        <span class = 'v10' style="display:none;"><span style='color:#FF0000;'>*</span>Inception Date:<br /></span>
    <input name='period_from'  class = 'v11' value = "<?php echo $incepd; ?>" onblur="validateg('<?php echo $fieldstovalidate; ?>','<?php echo $submitbtns; ?>');" id = 'period_from'   onfocus=showCalendar('',this,this,'".$period_from."','period_fromd',0,23,1); onfocus=returbcolorback('period_from'); style = 'height:21px;width:140px;display:none' type='text'  />
```

Now here's my if statement

```
if(strtolower($accountstatus) == 'animaldead')
{ $trutype = "selected";
  how will I show it here......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$style = 'none';
if(strtolower($accountstatus) == 'animaldead'){ 
   $trutype = "selected";
   $style = 'block';
}
```

and change span is like that

```
<span class = 'v10' style="display:<?php echo $style; ?>;">
```

using this way you don't need to copy the same code twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$block = "block";
  $none = "none";
if(strtolower($accountstatus) == 'animaldead')
{ $trutype = "selected";

?>     <span class = 'v10' style="display:<?php echo $block; ?>; "><span style='color:#FF0000;'>*</span>Inception Date:<br /></span>
    <input name='period_from'  class = 'v11' value = "<?php echo $incepd; ?>" onblur="validateg('<?php echo $fieldstovalidate; ?>','<?php echo $submitbtns; ?>');" id = 'period_from'   onfocus=showCalendar('',this,this,'".$period_from."','period_fromd',0,23,1); onfocus=returbcolorback('period_from'); style = 'height:21px;width:140px;display:none' type='text'  />
}
else{
<span class = 'v10' style="display:<?php echo $none; ?>; "><span style='color:#FF0000;'>*</span>Inception Date:<br /></span>
    <input name='period_from'  class = 'v11' value = "<?php echo $incepd; ?>" onblur="validateg('<?php echo $fieldstovalidate; ?>','<?php echo $submitbtns; ?>');" id = 'period_from'   onfocus=showCalendar('',this,this,'".$period_from."','period_fromd',0,23,1); onfocus=returbcolorback('period_from'); style = 'height:21px;width:140px;display:none' type='text'  />


}
```

You create 2 variables one for display block and one for display none. Now php and html can be written together so if it is == animaldead you put display:block as shown in the code above. Else you put display none... 
Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

A more elegent way than hardcoding the property inside the html tag is to use a special css class named for example hidden:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And when you render your HTML code you choose to add this class or not to your tag:

```
<span class = 'v10 <?php if (strtolower($accountstatus) == 'animaldead') echo '.hidden'; ?>'><span style='color:#FF0000;'>*</span>Inception Date:<br /></span>
```